# Anylogic: Error when run a model as standalone Java application

Tags: java, jvm, simulation, anylogic

I want to export my model as a standalone java application. When I want to run .bat file (my OS is windows 7), the following error appears; it says that it can not create Java virtual machine and the error which is given is about illegal access: deny.

[image]

what should I do?
And is there any other way to run a model on a computer where anylogic is not installed?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read the complete line. It doesn’t say something ”about illegal access: deny”, it says “Unrecognized option”. This is a sign that you should start caring about which Java version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of AnyLogic are you using? This option has been taken care of in the latest versions of AnyLogic.

Simply delete the following line in the .bat file

`set OPTIONS_XJAL=--illegal-access=deny`

Or something similar related to the option `--illegal-access=deny`

Depending on what Java version you are using this option might not be available. Most models (depending on what Java functions you use in your model) should run just fine. If they don't you need to check the error that they give and investigate further.

In the latest AnyLogic they handle this using the following code

```
set OPTIONS_XJAL=--illegal-access=deny
IF "%VERSION:~0,2%"=="1." set OPTIONS_XJAL=
```